# How to access Google Map API for fetching address depend on pincode?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I have used below code for fetching address depend on pincode but giving error

```
$http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=500082&sensor=true')
                .then(function (results) {
                    return results;
                });
```

I set

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

in config block

Error:-XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=500082&sensor=true. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:2808' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.